# How do I successfully import ScriptingBridge in xCode 6?

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-mavericks, spotify, scripting-bridge

I am making an basic app to control Spotify on OS X Mavericks using Xcode 6 and hopefully Scripting Bridge. I am using scripting bridge to interact with Spotify.

I have linked the scripting bridge library in Xcode via Project > General > Linked frameworks and libraries.

I have also create Spotify.h which I am trying to determine whether spotify is playing via ScriptingBridge.

When I come to build the spotify.h file throws a compile error in Xcode that import of scriptingbridge.h cannot be found on this line:

```html
#import <ScriptingBridge/ScriptingBridge.h>

From



/*
 * Spotify.h
 */

#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#import <ScriptingBridge/ScriptingBridge.h>

@class SpotifyApplication, SpotifyTrack, SpotifyApplication;

enum SpotifyEPlS {
 SpotifyEPlSStopped = 'kPSS',
 SpotifyEPlSPlaying = 'kPSP',
 SpotifyEPlSPaused = 'kPSp'
};
typedef enum SpotifyEPlS SpotifyEPlS;



/*
 * Spotify Suite
 */

// The Spotify application.
@interface SpotifyApplication : SBApplication

@property (copy, readonly) SpotifyTrack *currentTrack;  // The current playing track.
@property NSInteger soundVolume;  // The sound output volume (0 = minimum, 100 = maximum)
@property (readonly) SpotifyEPlS playerState;  // Is Spotify stopped, paused, or playing?
@property double playerPosition;  // The player’s position within the currently playing track in seconds.
@property (readonly) BOOL repeatingEnabled;  // Is repeating enabled in the current playback context?
@property BOOL repeating;  // Is repeating on or off?
@property (readonly) BOOL shufflingEnabled;  // Is shuffling enabled in the current playback context?
@property BOOL shuffling;  // Is shuffling on or off?

- (void) nextTrack;  // Skip to the next track.
- (void) previousTrack;  // Skip to the previous track.
- (void) playpause;  // Toggle play/pause.
- (void) pause;  // Pause playback.
- (void) play;  // Resume playback.
- (void) playTrack:(NSString *)x inContext:(NSString *)inContext;  // Start playback of a track in the given context.

@end

// A Spotify track.
@interface SpotifyTrack : SBObject

@property (copy, readonly) NSString *artist;  // The artist of the track.
@property (copy, readonly) NSString *album;  // The album of the track.
@property (readonly) NSInteger discNumber;  // The disc number of the track.
@property (readonly) NSInteger duration;  // The length of the track in seconds.
@property (readonly) NSInteger playedCount;  // The number of times this track has been played.
@property (readonly) NSInteger trackNumber;  // The index of the track in its album.
@property (readonly) BOOL starred;  // Is the track starred?
@property (readonly) NSInteger popularity;  // How popular is this track? 0-100
- (NSString *) id;  // The ID of the item.
@property (copy, readonly) NSString *name;  // The name of the track.
@property (copy, readonly) NSImage *artwork;  // The track's album cover.
@property (copy, readonly) NSString *albumArtist;  // That album artist of the track.
@property (copy) NSString *spotifyUrl;  // The URL of the track.


@end



/*
 * Standard Suite
 */

// The application's top level scripting object.
@interface SpotifyApplication (StandardSuite)

@property (copy, readonly) NSString *name;  // The name of the application.
@property (readonly) BOOL frontmost;  // Is this the frontmost (active) application?
@property (copy, readonly) NSString *version;  // The version of the application.

@end
```

See image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZ2oF.png

What am I doing wrong for this to fail to build?

Comment: The most helpful thing in this case would be to see the raw build log for this file, particularly including the compile command.  My only guess without that is that you have either your deployment target or SDK set to something really old — I think it would have to be pre-10.5.